# snakemake get number of input of a rule

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to do something simple: get the number of input that has a `snakemake` rules, and use this value in my shell commands.
I have a working solution with the trick below, but this is very ugly and I guess/hope there is something more pretty to get `N`?

```
rule x:
    input:
        files = ["file1", "file2"],
    output:
        "output.txt"
    shell:
        """
        N=$(echo {input.files} | tr ' ' '\\n' | wc -l); # this returns 2, but the code is ugly!
        touch {output}
        """
```

Comment: Besides using a function in the "params" section, as suggested in @euronion's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77244499/1878788), another way of doing would be to use a "run" section where you can use whatever python code you need before generating a string to pass to the `shell` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a dedicated `params` entry in combination with a function

```py
rule x:
    input:
        files = ["file1", "file2"],
    params:
        no_inputs=lambda wildcards, input: len(input.files)
    output:
        "output.txt"
    shell:
        """
        N={params.no_inputs}
        touch {output}
        """
```

(can't test it right now)

see here: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thanks! I thought only wildcards were accepted as input of lambda functions in the params

Comment: Yes ;-) it's a bit hidden in the documentation that `wildcards` has to be passed, but also `input`, `output`, `threads`, and `resources` are supported